# Determine whether $f :\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by f(x)=$x^3+1$ is surjective or not.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1) Determine whether the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$  given by $f(x)=x^3+1$ is surjective  or not. Explain your answer carefully with precise arguments.

Solution
This function is surjective, because for every integer y there is  an integer $x$ such that
$f(x)=y$.
to see this $f(x)= y$ if and only if $x^3+1=y$, which holds if and only if $x=y^3+1$.

*I need help with this one can someone give me hints on how to solve this question.*

2) Decide whether true or false, and provide a clear explanation: If $f,g: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ are functions such that $f$ is injective (i.e., is 1-1) and $g$ is surjective (i.e., is onto), then the composition ($f\circ g$) is both injective and surjective.

Comment: Why does it hold if $x=y^3+1$?

Comment: i think i just gave a guess line there. is it a trivial one???

Comment: If $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = e^x$, then it is false.

Comment: correct me if iam wrong

Comment: I guess you mean $x^3+1=y$ iff $x=(y-1)^{1/3}$?